# HP-UX Boot from SAN

Tags: hp-ux

Does anybody knows how to make HP-UX boot from SAN?
Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm totally disappointed by HP's lack of documentation.

The server is RX8640 with HP-UX 11.31

Comment: The only thing I know about booting from SAN is that your interfaces are required to support it and I know not all firmware levels do.

Comment: [Please don't cross-post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). (http://serverfault.com/questions/401761/hp-ux-boot-from-san) Pick one site, and if it doesn't get attention and there is another good fit for your question, ask for moderators to migrate (via a custom flag). I don't know HP-UX at all, but wouldn't the type of SAN, type of HBA, and firmware levels potentially be important here?

Comment: Basically you have to enter the management processor and enter the WWN to boot from. Did you already try that?